# Python Export Dictionary to CSV

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv

I'm new in Python and I've been trying to create csv file and save each result in a new row. The results consist of several rows and each line should be captured in csv. However, my csv file separate each letter into new row. I also need to add new key values for the filename, but I dont know how to get the image filename (input is images). I used the search bar searching for similar case/recommended solution but still stumped. Thanks in advance.

```
with open('glaresss_result.csv','wt') as f:
f.write(",".join(res1.keys()) + "\n")
for imgpath in glob.glob(os.path.join(TARGET_DIR, "*.png")):
    res1,res = send_request_qcglare(imgpath)
    for row in zip(*res1.values()):
        f.write(",".join(str(n) for n in row) + "\n")
f.close()
```

dictionary `res1` printed during the iteration returns:

```
{'glare': 'Passed', 'brightness': 'Passed'}
```

The results should be like this (got 3 rows):

- **glare      brightness**
- Passed    Passed
- Passed    Passed
- Passed.   Passed

But the current output looks like this:

[image: Current output in csv]

Comment: could you please provide the data of the dictionary `res1` in your question (as text please)?

Comment: res1 is a result from a function called send_request_qcglare. If I print res1, it will be like this:- {'glare': 'Passed', 'brightness': 'Passed'}{'glare': 'Passed', 'brightness': 'Passed'}{'glare': 'Passed', 'brightness': 'Passed'}{'glare': 'Passed', 'brightness': 'Passed'}. It repeated several times due to the total image used is 4. So it is the result of 4 images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things I changed.

- `w` is enough, since `t` for text mode is default
- no need to close the csv when using a context manager
- no need for zip and `str(n) for n in row`. Just join the 2 values of the dictionary

**UPDATED**

```
with open('glaresss_result.csv','w') as f: 
    f.write(",".join([*res1] + ['filename']) + "\n") # replace filename with whatever columnname you want
    for imgpath in glob.glob(os.path.join(TARGET_DIR, "*.png")):
        res1,res = send_request_qcglare(imgpath)
        f.write(",".join([*res1.values()] + [imgpath]) + "\n") # imgpath (which needs to be a string) will be the value of each row, replace with whatever you suits
```

Comment: It works!!!! Thanks a lot, you're a lifesaver . 1 more curiosity, is it possible to add 1 more key that hold image filename as its value?

Comment: you're welcome, thank me with accepting/voting the answer :) I updated my answer to add another column with the filename/path or whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do more with data, you might want to check out the pandas library.
In your use case p.ex `DataFrame.from_records`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html

It provides a lot of out of the box functionalities to read, transform and write data.

```py
import pandas as pd
results = []
for imgpath in glob.glob(os.path.join(TARGET_DIR, "*.png")):
    res1,res = send_request_qcglare(imgpath)
    result.append(res1)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)
df.to_csv("glaresss_result.csv", index=False)
```